# Copy iTunes playlist via Home Sharing

Tags: itunes, home-sharing

I'm trying to copy an iTunes playlist from a Mac to a PC via the Home Sharing function. 
When dragging the required playlist to the destination Library I get a red-cross-circle for the cursor.

Trying to copy single tracks also doesn't work.

Both iTunes are logged into the same account.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem but I discovered how to do it.
Don't drag the playlist to the list of playlists from the other computer.
Create a new blank playlist and then drag the playlist you want to copy over it. That should work. Luck!